# How to fetch all the data from a table including table Id

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have written the following query using Join to fetch the data from different tables. This query is working fine on MySQL , it fetching out all the data form the database, but when i writ this query in PHP, then it fetches out all the data except `StudentId`. When i use `print_r` then it shows `studentId` column as empty.
Kindly guide me what i am missing here?

Model

```
public function student_profile($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('student');
    $this->db->join('student_marks',                'student.studentId= student_marks.studentId','left');
    $this->db->join('sports',                       'student.studentId= sports.studentId','left');
    $this->db->join('extra_curricular_activities',  'student.studentId= extra_curricular_activities.studentId','left'   );
    $this->db->where('student.studentId', $id);

    $query=     $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();


    }
```

Controller

```
        if ($user_type=='Student')  
        {
            if ($LoginData= $this->loginmodel->studentLogin($username,$password))
            {
                foreach($LoginData as $UserId)
                {
                    $currentId= $UserId->StudentId;                         
                }

                $data['students_data']=         $this->loginmodel->student_profile($currentId);

                $this->load->view('students',$data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [StudentId] => 
            [StudentName] => Ahmed
            [UserId] => 57502
            [Password] => 28101
            [Batch] => 2009
            [Email] => ahmed@Hotmail.com
            [PhoneNumber] => 02134663028
            [DegreeId] => 1
            [in_semester] => 1
            [StudentMarksId] => 15
            [SemisterCourseId] => 1
            [AssignmentMarks] => 9
            [QuizMarks] => 9
            [ClassTestMarks] => 9
            [FinalMarks] => 45
            [Grades] => F
            [FYPMarks] => 9
            [Attendence] => 
            [GPA] => 0
            [OLQ] => 9
            [InstructorComments] => Satisfactory !!
            [InstructorRatings] => 9
            [Result] => Failed
            [Active] => No
            [SportsId] => 
            [Squash] => 
            [FootBall] => 
            [Cricket] => 
            [Hocky] => 
            [Swimming] => 
            [ExtraActivitiesId] => 
            [DebateCompetition] => 
            [QuizCompetition] => 
            [QiratCompetition] => 
            [DrillCompetition] => 
            [Others] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [StudentId] => 
            [StudentName] => Ahmed
            [UserId] => 57502
            [Password] => 28101
            [Batch] => 2009
            [Email] => ahmed@Hotmail.com
            [PhoneNumber] => 02134663028
            [DegreeId] => 1
            [in_semester] => 1
            [StudentMarksId] => 16
            [SemisterCourseId] => 2
            [AssignmentMarks] => 2
            [QuizMarks] => 2
            [ClassTestMarks] => 2
            [FinalMarks] => 10
            [Grades] => F
            [FYPMarks] => 2
            [Attendence] => 
            [GPA] => 0
            [OLQ] => 2
            [InstructorComments] => 
            [InstructorRatings] => 0
            [Result] => Failed
            [Active] => No
            [SportsId] => 
            [Squash] => 
            [FootBall] => 
            [Cricket] => 
            [Hocky] => 
            [Swimming] => 
            [ExtraActivitiesId] => 
            [DebateCompetition] => 
            [QuizCompetition] => 
            [QiratCompetition] => 
            [DrillCompetition] => 
            [Others] => 
        )
```

Comment: print your query using $this->db->last_query() and manually execute this in database and see what you are getting in the result

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `LEFT` join over your tables and they share same column name for `studentId` so from mysql the last column is picked from your any joined table and it has the null you should use aliases for your query,  and give new aliases to columns that has the same name like below `s.studentId AS student_id`

```
function student_profile($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*,s.studentId AS student_id');
    $this->db->from('student s');
    $this->db->join('student_marks sm', 's.studentId= sm.studentId', 'left');
    $this->db->join('sports sp', 's.studentId= sp.studentId', 'left');
    $this->db->join('extra_curricular_activities e', 's.studentId= e.studentId', 'left');
    $this->db->where('s.studentId', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

When result will be fetched you have a correct student id on `[student_id]`,
Other way to do this just select only needed columns donot select `*`

Comment: Thanks for the help :) This code is not giving me the following error message `Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'student.studentId' in 'where clause'

SELECT *, `s`.`studentId` AS student_id FROM (`student` s) LEFT JOIN `student_marks` sm ON `s`.`studentId`= `sm`.`studentId` LEFT JOIN `sports` sp ON `s`.`studentId`= `sp`.`studentId` LEFT JOIN `extra_curricular_activities` e ON `s`.`studentId`= `e`.`studentId` WHERE `student`.`studentId` = '41'`

Comment: see my updated answer change where clause to `$this->db->where('s.studentId', $id);`